# Asp.net Role isn't working as it should

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I setup role management such that only user with the role "Employee" can view a page.  However it is allowing anyone who is logged in to view the page, how do I change it so only those user who is both logged in and have the role "Employee" for view my page?

```
      <location path="About.aspx">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
            <allow roles="Employee"/>
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t.aspx):

> At run time, the authorization module iterates through the allow and
>   deny elements, starting at the most local configuration file, until
>   the authorization module finds the first access rule that fits a
>   particular user account. Then, the authorization module grants or
>   denies access to a URL resource depending on whether the first access
>   rule found is an allow or a deny rule

Based on that explanation, you should allow Employees (because that will match first), and then deny everyone else.

```
  <location path="About.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Employee"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```